# Combobox first values should be null

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I fill combobox like that. want to firts was null. how can i do tthat?

```
    private void txtLoadname_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HashSet<string> LoadName = new HashSet<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            LoadName.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["loadNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString());
        }
        txtLoadname.DataSource = LoadName.ToList();


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding LoadName.Add(null); before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

add this line just before the last line:

```
LoadName.InsertAt(0,"");
```